# Using AJAX rather than sending a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

What would be the equivalent of using AJAX rather than sending a form in this case

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <div style="padding-left: 10 px:"></div>
 <input id ="datetime" style="display:none;" type="text" name="datetime" VALUE="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" SIZE="5"   > 
 <A  HREF="#" onClick="cal.select(document.forms[0].datetime,'anchor','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;"             
     TITLE="cal.select(document.forms['example'].datetime,'anchor','MM/dd/yyyy'); return false;" 
     NAME="anchor" ID="anchor"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>
 </A>
 <input style="font-size: Bold 8pt;" id = "done" type="submit" value="Done" />
</form>
```

I want to use the AJAX post to get my new variables rather than sending the form.

Comment: Why don't you read the [**documentation for $.ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and find out ?

Comment: Dunno...I argue you don't even know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It would just be

```
$("#done").click(function() {
    $.post("/",{"datetime": $("#datetime").val()});
    return false;
})
```

More about `$.post`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Would i put this into another JS file?
Also, I wouldn't need to have a submit input would I?

Comment: No, just make sure you include jQuery and put it in a `<script>` tag at the end of the page.

Comment: Should I still have the input tag for the submit?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer (though you probably want to look at the duplicate question notice)